# How to Use both Scala and Python in a same Spark project?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Is that possible to pipe **Spark RDD** to Python?

Because I need a python library to do some calculation on my data, but my main Spark project is based on Scala. 
Is there a way to mix them both or let python access the same spark context?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your code in PySpark but not all Python libraries can take rdds. Which Python library are you using?

Comment: Do you wan the results of the Spark operations, or do you want the raw RDD to manipulate in Python.  The former is not only possible, it's common in the world of Big Data.  Writing a Python plug-in for a Spark result requires proper attention to detail, but is often a good solution.

How did your Internet search not turn up this information?  What search terms did you use?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Please post your Spark API and the Python level you want to interface with it.

Comment: I want to use [Jieba](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba) for text processing, which is a Chinese word segmentation library.  
And I use Spark Streaming + Kafka for Data collecting. Now the problem is I need to pipe raw data to Python for doing text processing, then send the result back to other Scala code for other analyzing.

Comment: You can use pipe in Spark.From which you can basically send the data and get the output of the external program as input.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can indeed pipe out to a python script using Scala and Spark and a regular Python script.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print "hello " + line
```

**spark-shell (scala)**

```
val data = List("john","paul","george","ringo")

val dataRDD = sc.makeRDD(data)

val scriptPath = "./test.py"

val pipeRDD = dataRDD.pipe(scriptPath)

pipeRDD.foreach(println)
```

**Output**

hello john

hello ringo

hello george

hello paul

Comment: Only locally on my laptop, not on a cluster.

Comment: Yes, I know this method, but the python script is running on executor, so I have a question that if I pipe too much data to external script, will the worker crash ? I mean, the external Python script is not parallel computing.

Comment: @WilsonLiao records are piped 1 item at a time, so as long as your external script can handle 1 RDD element worth of data (and doesn't accumulate state while it is running), you should be fine. The documentation for the `pipe` function in scala is helpful:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L742

Answer (score 11):

You can run the Python code via **Pipe** in Spark.

With pipe(), you can write a transformation of an RDD that reads each RDD element from standard input as String, manipulates that String as per script instruction, and then writes the result as String to standard output.

SparkContext.addFile(path), we can add up list of files for each of the worker nodes to download when a Spark job starts.All the worker node will have their copy of the script thus we will be getting parallel operation by pipe. We need to install all the libraries and dependency prior to it on all the worker and executor node.

**Example :**

**Python File** : Code for making Input data to Uppercase

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.upper()
```

**Spark Code** : For Piping the data

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Pipe")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val distScript = "/path/on/driver/PipeScript.py"
val distScriptName = "PipeScript.py"
sc.addFile(distScript)
val ipData = sc.parallelize(List("asd","xyz","zxcz","sdfsfd","Ssdfd","Sdfsf"))
val opData = ipData.pipe(SparkFiles.get(distScriptName))
opData.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly, as long as you take the data from `scala` and covert it to [`RDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) or [`SparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext) then you'll be able to use [`pyspark`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/) to manipulate the data using Spark Python API.

There's also a [programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframes) that you can follow to utilize the different languages within `spark`

Comment: One cannot use both scala and pyspark on the same RDD. It is possible in Notebooks (Zeppelin/Jupyter) by converting your RDD to Dataframe/Dataset and  then register it as temporary view. Other option is pipe as explained above.