# spark scala and python interlinking

Tags: python-2.7, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have few questions:

1) [How to Use both Scala and Python in a same Spark project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975636/how-to-use-both-scala-and-python-in-a-same-spark-project)

I know we can use the pipe operator to start a different process to run the python commands, but the issue is that on the worker node they are not in part of same jvm but a subprocess which can crash the worker. 
Am I correct, and  if so, are there any suggestion to handle this? If I use hdfs to write and read back it will make it more expensive in terms of processing.

2) I have many models which are written in python and we want to use spark to run those models without changing (very imp) on cluster and to get the scalability. What direction I should be thinking on when writing a custom framework in scala to do that.

Python does not scale much on cluster and scala has the above issue of sub process.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I didn't get your question. You want to run Scala Via Python or Python via Scala? Or any solution could work for you?

Comment: I want to basically create something in scala and based on the keys and granularity it will be distribued across the cluster to run the functions written in different languages like scala,r etc. Dataframes should be interchangeable between lanuages. For example:- we pass spark rdd to python function and run it on cluster and get the result back in rdd and then result rdd/df is fed into different scala function again on cluster.Whole dag across interchangeable language runs seamlessly on calling the action