# How to specify a python environment for running a scala job in spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, virtualenv

I am trying to run a python script from a scala job in Spark (as in 
[How to Use both Scala and Python in a same Spark project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975636/how-to-use-both-scala-and-python-in-a-same-spark-project), the python script is called from within the scala job). The problem is that I need to run the python script in a specific environment, but the --py-files option for specifying dependencies does not work when the jar only contains the scala job. The option works correctly when the jar contains a .py, so I'm guessing the problem comes from the expectation of a python job. Does anyone have a work-around? Is there a way to specify a scala environment / dependencies in which I could insert python dependencies ?