# Is it possible to call a python function from Scala(spark)

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a spark job that requires a column to be added to a dataframe using a function written in python. The rest of the processing is done using Scala.

I have found examples of how to call a Java/Scala function from pyspark:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/110844/is-it-possible-to-call-a-scala-function-in-pythonp.html
- http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/09/01/spark-calling-scala-code-from-pyspark.html

The only examples I have found to send data the other way is using `pipe`

- [How to Use both Scala and Python in a same Spark project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975636/how-to-use-both-scala-and-python-in-a-same-spark-project)

Is it possible for me to send the entire dataframe to a python function, have the function manipulate the data and add additional columns and then send the resulting dataframe back to the calling Scala function?

If this isn't possible my current solution is to run a pyspark process and call multiple Scala functions to manipulate the dataframe, this isn't ideal.

Comment: While theoretically possible (via. Py4j callbacks) it is not worth the hustle. Spark is designed to make guest interactions easy, not the other way around. If you want to make things easier - just consolidate a whole Scala Pipeline in a single wrapper function. Or use notebook like Databricks or Zeppelin. But for a single functions it almost always better to rewrite the thing.

Comment: Unfortunately the effort to rewrite the function would be massive. It makes use of some libraries which have no jvm based equivalent. I have also already wrapped the pipeline in a single function. I was hoping i had missed something. ☹ looks like I'm stuck using python as my entry point

Comment: One more approach is to use pickled object and create `PythonFunction` and `UserDefinedPythonFunction` manually from Java but I would advise against that.

Comment: @roblovelock: did you find some solution for this? we need something similar?

Comment: no, unfortunately, I didn't. I hit a similar issue last week and decided to write the solution in python for this very reason. I will have a look a bit later to see if I can solve this once and for all.

Comment: Sure. You can do what you want. Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76802913/6380624

Answer (score 1):

Just register a UDF from Python, and then from Scala evaluate an SQL statement that uses the function against a DataFrame - works like a charm, just tried it ;)
https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook is a good way to run a notebook in Toree that mixes Scala and Python code calling the same Spark context.

Comment: Hi Egor, do you want to post the sample for reference?

Comment: Apparently, he does not :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this post:

[Machine Learning with Jupyter using Scala, Spark and Python: The Setup](https://medium.com/@faizanahemad/machine-learning-with-jupyter-using-scala-spark-and-python-the-setup-62d05b0c7f56)

It shows you how to set up a Jupyter notebook that used both Spark and Python. If you are just experimenting with data that might be enough.