# UDFs in Spark pipelines

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I create a UDF in python to compute an array of dates between two date columns in a table and register it to the spark session. I use this UDF in a pipeline to compute a new column.

Now when I save this pipeline to HDFS and expect it to be read back for execution in a different program(with a different spark session), the UDF is not available because its not globally registered anywhere. Since the process is generic and needs to run multiple pipelines, I dont want to add the UDF definition and register it to the spark session there.

Is there anyway for me to register UDFs globally across all spark session?

Can I add this in as a dependency somehow in a neat maintainable manner?

Comment: I saw your question and wanted to ask how are you adding udf in pipeline?

Comment: I use an SQLTransformer to create sql based transformations. If I use a spark session that has the udf registered on it, then I can use the UDF in the SQLTransformer and put that into a pipeline.

Comment: I get this error when using udf's "Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type %s." % type(stage))
TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <type 'function'>.

Comment: You need to post the code for be to get it. Might be better to ask as a separate question. Just mention me on the comments and I'll try to answer it too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem trying to save it from python and import it in scala.

- I think I will just use SQL to do what I want to do.
- I also saw [I could use python *.py fil*e in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975636/how-to-use-both-scala-and-python-in-a-same-spark-project), but I do not find yet a way to use it in a UDF transformer.
- If you want to use `pyspark` from a java pipeline think you can use the jar of the UDF using `sql_context.udf.registerJavaFunction` (or 
  `sql_context.sql("CREATE function newF as 'f' USING JAR 'udf.jar'")`), this seemed to work for me but I dont care since I need
     to do python => scala.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.