# Spark Pipe function throws No such file or directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipe

I am running the spark pipe function on EMR master server in REPL just to test out the pipe functionality. I am using the following examples

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32978183/8876462
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/pipe-in-spark/
http://hadoop-makeitsimple.blogspot.com/2016/05/pipe-in-spark.html
```

This is my code ::

```
import org.apache.spark._
val distScript = "/home/hadoop/PipeEx.sh"
val distScriptName = "PipeEx.sh"
sc.addFile(distScript)
val ipData = 
sc.parallelize(List("asd","xyz","zxcz","sdfsfd","Ssdfd","Sdfsf"))
val opData = ipData.pipe(SparkFiles.get(distScriptName))
opData.foreach(println)
```

I have tried different things like making the file executable, placed in file in /usr/lib/spark/bin as suggested in another post. I changed the distScript to say

```
"file:///home/hadoop/PipeEx.sh"
```

I always get no such file or directory in `tmp/spark*/userFiles*` location. I have tried to access and run the shell program from the tmp location and it runs fine. 
My shell script is the same as http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/pipe-in-spark/

Here is the first part of the log::

```
[Stage 9:>                                                          (0 + 2) 
/ 2]18/03/19 19:58:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 
72, ip-172-31-42-11.ec2.internal, executor 9): java.io.IOException: Cannot 
run program "/mnt/tmp/spark-bdd582ec-a5ac-4bb1-874e-832cd5427b18/userFiles-
497f6051-6f49-4268-b9c5-a28c2ad5edc6/PipeEx.sh": error=2, No such file or 
directory
```

Does any one have any idea? I am using Spark 2.2.1 and scala 2.11.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this , once I removed the 
    SparkFiles.get(distScriptName)
command. 
So my final code looks like this

```
val distScript = "/home/hadoop/PipeEx.sh"
val distScriptName = "./PipeEx.sh"
sc.addFile(distScript)

val ipData = sc.parallelize(List("asd","xyz","zxcz","sdfsfd","Ssdfd","Sdfsf"))
val opData = ipData.pipe(distScriptName)
opData.collect().foreach(println)
```

I am not very sure why removing the SparkFiles.get() solved the problem